# Screen saver won't activate

Tags: windows-10, power-management, screensaver

I am using a Intel computer stick plugged directly into the HDMI on the TV. Running Windows 10. I'm unable to setup my computer to "auto-lock". In the power settings, I set it to turn the display off after 3 hours. In the screen saver settings, I've ticked the box to "require password on resume". Neither of these options are working currently. The monitor does not go into screen saver mode, nor will it turn off after 3 hours. Yes, I have a password on my account which is entered upon every restart.

Research shows that I need to delete a couple registry keys, but neither of them currently exist. Previewing of the screen saver functions properly. Other than that, I have been unable to find a solution.

Screenshot:
[image: screensaver page]

Comment: Perhaps your issue is a USB gamepad plugged in? http://superuser.com/questions/979855/gamepad-prevents-screensaver-from-starting-on-windows-10

Comment: Try to remove ALL USB input devices if any (mouse, keyboard, gamepad,..) and see if it will work. Check in device manager what you have connected to USB.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it turned out to be a USB Game Controller, as mentioned in the comments. Once I unplugged it, my screensaver came on right at the 1 minute setting.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments it appears another device could be keeping your PC awake. Even programs (autohotkey) could cause if they emulate user input, or even some network device:
[image: Allow this device to wake the computer]

So the screensaver when set for 1min doesn't even work? You could start disabling things & try a clean boot of windows ([kb929135](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135), [kb331796](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/331796)) to isolate the cause